# How to slice or limit dynamic nested array nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, multidimensional-array, dynamic, slice

How to slice data in nested array?
I want to use it with pagination for limit the data for display.
I have try it with **object key** but only limit the nested array without show parent data

I am trying use object key like this. The ouput is correct but not show the parent like data1, data2, etc

```
  dataJson.map(d => {
    for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(d).length;i++){
      let rev = d[Object.keys(d)].slice(1 * 2 - 2, 1 * 2);
      console.log(rev);
   }
  })
```

output

```
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "John" 
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "James" 
    }

    {
      id: 1,
      name: "May" 
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Joe" 
    }
```

structure data json in single object array

```
 "data": [
    {
      "data 1": [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "John" 
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "James" 
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "James" 
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data 2": [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "May" 
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Joe" 
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Din" 
        }
      ]
    },
    data 3,
    many data others
 ]
```

i want to display it like this (limit data and show 2 data from nested array)
with function slice

```
 "data": [
    {
      "data 1": [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "John" 
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "James" 
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data 2": [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "May" 
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Joe" 
        }
      ]
    },
 ]
```

Comment: asked this question without any attempt ? show us what you write so far.

Comment: hi Nur, thanks for comment. i have update the questions and do what i did before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See more about [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
let data = [{ "data 1": [{ id: 1, name: "John" }, { id: 2, name: "James" }, { id: 3, name: "James" }] }, { "data 2": [{ id: 1, name: "May" }, { id: 2, name: "Joe" }, { id: 3, name: "Din" }] },]
let out = data.map(v => {
    let obj = {}
    for (let [k, arr] of Object.entries(v))
        obj[k] = arr.slice(0, 2);

    return obj
});
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is your requirement**

```
    var array = [];
var data = []
var data1 = [{ name: 's' }, { name: 'v' }, { name: 'c' }];
var data2 = [{ name: 's' }, { name: 'v' }, { name: 'c' }];

array['data'] = data;
data['data 1'] = data1;
data['data 2'] = data2;

for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    array.data['data ' + i].splice(2, 1)

}
console.log(array);
```

**OutPut:**

```
[
  data: [
    'data 1': [ [Object], [Object] ],
    'data 2': [ [Object], [Object] ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: thank you.
but not solved my problem yet